# Where can I find road atlas for Ireland including campsites?

Tags: camping, maps, ireland

Could someone recommend a road atlas for Ireland (and N. Ireland) with campsites marked on it?

EDIT: I am looking for "real" paper map/atlas. I will be camping in a tent.

Comment: Generally we don't do recommendations but I know from experience that finding books/maps of campsites is not always easy for a given location so I think this is a good question.

Comment: Does it need to be paperbased, or would you like a computer/tablet/internet based answer?

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, are you camping or taking a caravan/mobile home/camper van? In Ireland caravaning has certain problems which i'll elaborate if applicable.

Comment: **1.** In much of the West of Ireland, wild camping is no problem. I've done it many times (it was our family holidays every year). **2.** I have yet to see any map of Ireland which didn't include both the North and the Republic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The tourist information offices in Ireland ([here's a list from the Irish Tourist Organisation, 'Discover Ireland'](http://www.discoverireland.ie/CMSPages/PortalTemplate.aspx?aliaspath=%2fSearch%2fResults&=&catid=10199&areaid=&countyid=&locationid=969&lcid=1&sort=2&pagesize=80)) sell booklets with maps of campsites. I got one in the Dublin office for €5. It lists loads of campsites, has some photographs of them, lists details (opening days, phone numbers, directions, facilities, etc.). They also sell booklets of B&B's/Hotels.

That has an overview map, but wouldn't count as a street atlas. As far as I know most road atlases (which can be bought almost anywhere, in many bookshops and newsagents around the country) will mark campsites, they won't have the level of detail (like phone numbers so you can ring ahead and book or get directions) that the one from the tourist information office will have, so I recommend supplimenting your street atlas with this campsite directory.

Are you camping, or taking a caravan/mobile home. *(Caravaning in Ireland has other problems)*

Comment: @Rory: When you say "it lists loads of campsites" should we interpret this as meaning it doesn't attempty to list all campsites?

Comment: Ireland is a small place (350 miles by 150 miles), it lists at least 100 campsites, from all over the country. I don't know how many campsites there are in Ireland, but I would be suprised if it had less than 90% of the campsites.